# Fama MacBeth regression in R

Tags: r, finance

I am trying to do Fama Macbeth regression on some tradable factors using 5-year rolling window updated monthly.

I have the data of excess returns of 1000 stocks and the data of certain risk factors from July 1997 and December 2014.

However, I am very new to R and don't know how to deal with it correctly.

I have saw an example before. However it didn't involve rolling. Besides, I don't know how to get Newey-West t-statistic.

```
library(foreign)
test<-read.dta("http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/test_data.dta")
num=500; T=10;
#step1: 500 time-series regressions
betas <- matrix(nrow=num, ncol=2)
colnames(betas) <- c("Intercept", "beta")
for (i in 1:num) {
  betas[i,] <- coef(lm(y~x, test[test$firmid==i,]))
}
test$betas <- rep(betas[,2],each=T)
#step2: 10 cross-section regressions
factor_premia <- matrix(nrow=T)
colnames(factor_premia) = "Ret_Premium"
for (j in 1:T) {
  factor_premia[j] <- coef(lm(y~betas, test[test$year==j,]))[2]
}
factor_risk_premia <- mean(factor_premia)
```

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code started?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What have you tried? Please [edit] your question (do *not* add comments) and provide your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Include any error messages and stack traces. You may want to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I post questions and I am new to R. @Wookies-Will-Code